# button with random function jqt

Tags: jquery, button, random, jqtouch

i'm an absolute beginner - so after days of searching i'm asking for help:
i have a small web app in jqtouch an want the user to be able to tap on an image = button, which jumps to a randomly chosen id = page.

how am i doing this?
something like this is not working:

header:

```
var randomlinks=new Array()

randomlinks[0]="page100"
randomlinks[1]="page120"
randomlinks[1]="page130"

function randomlink(){
document.location='#' + randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}
function MM_callJS(jsStr) { //v2.0
  return eval(jsStr)
}
```

body:

```
<a href="#" class="dissolve"><img src="images/randombutton.png" class="something" onClick="MM_callJS('randomlink()')"></a>
```

thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
var randomlinks=[];

randomlinks[0]="page100"
randomlinks[1]="page120"
randomlinks[2]="page130"

function randomlink(){
 var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length);
 window.location.href ='#' + randomlinks[idx];
}
```

Comment: hmm, okay, sorry, i filled in the numbers, but the page which is calld is not moving in. nothing happens.var randomlinks=[];

randomlinks[0]="page100"
randomlinks[1]="page120"
randomlinks[2]="page130"

function randomlink(){
 var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length);
 window.location.href ='#' + randomlinks[idx];
}

Comment: And here comes the solution (just 2 more lines), enjoy:

var randomlinks=[];

randomlinks[]="page100"
randomlinks[]="page120"
randomlinks[]="page130"

function randomlink(){
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length);

jQT.goTo('#' + randomlinks[idx], 'dissolve');
$('#' + randomlinks[idx]).load(targetURL);
}

Comment: I think that there was an error in the way i declared elements in th array!I corrected it